# Calculate the average with weight

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list:

```
list = {{17, 2}, {11.55, 3}, {18.5, 1}, {14.2, 1}, {14.25, 2}, {11.5,3}, {15, 2}, {11, 3},{10.8, 3}};
```

I wish to calculate:

```
  (17*2+11.5*3+18.5*1+14.2*1+14.25*2+...+10.8*3)/(2+3+1+2+...+3)
```

How can I use list manipulation?

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WeightedData.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make @I.M.'s comment explicit:

```
list = {{17, 2}, {11.55, 3}, {18.5, 1}, {14.2, 1}, {14.25, 2},
        {11.5, 3}, {15, 2}, {11, 3}, {10.8, 3}};

data = WeightedData @@ Transpose[list];

Mean[data]
(*    12.9875    *)

Variance[data]
(*    6.53654    *)
```

Comment: WeightedData is a fruitful function I have not known it!! Thank you so much for your answer. It was so interesting!!!

Answer (score 3):

Using list manipulation (and showing the steps):

```
list = {{17, 2}, {11.55, 3}, {18.5, 1}, {14.2, 1}, {14.25, 2}, {11.5, 
    3}, {15, 2}, {11, 3}, {10.8, 3}};

Times @@@ list
```

> {34, 34.65, 18.5, 14.2, 28.5, 34.5, 30, 33, 32.4}

```
Total@(Times @@@ list)
```

> 259.75

```
Total@list[[All, 2]]
```

> 20

Putting it together in one step:

```
Total@(Times @@@ list)/Total@list[[All, 2]]
```

> 12.9875

Of course, this is why functions are written, i.e., to reduce the work. Note that to find variance and stdev using list manipulation would become difficult and error-prone and the `WeightedData` approach is more suitable.

Answer (score 3):

`WeightedData` is both convenient and efficient. For the sake of variety you can also do:

```
wA = #.Normalize[#2, Total] & @@ Transpose @ # &;
wA @ list
```

> ```
> 12.9875
> ```

and for fun:

[image]

```
☺ = #.#2/(+## & @@ #2) & @@ (#\[Transpose]) &;
☺ @ list
```

> ```
> 12.9875
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Syed, also the numbers inside the list can be used also #1, #2

```
Total[{#1*#2} & @@@ list]/Total[list[[All, 2]]]
```

12.98

Comment: I like your answer!!! using # in functions is very interesting and amazing